How to in SidePanel get Chrome Theme colors?
I would like to create Chrome Extension with sidePanel. I can't find solution how to get Chrome Browser Theme colors and use it in my sidePanel. I would like to my extension sidePanel looks exactly the same like others default Chrome sidePanels like ex. Reading List. It seams be a simple thing for example using CSS variables, but I can't find any informations about this.
Actually I don't have an idea how to do this. I tried check in DevTools but it doesn't work for default Chrome sidePanels.

There's no way, it's not implemented.

@woxxom - Really? Are you 100% sure? Default SidePanels use Chrome theme styles so I think it should be possible to do in custom extension also?

Absolutely sure, see the documentation.
